# Attach a context menu to a GWT MenuItem

Tags: gwt

A GWT MenuItem extends UIObject - any idea how I can add event handlers to it for example I want a special context menu for right-clicking on a MenuItem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use underlying element of the MenuItem object:

```
final Element element = menuItem.getElement();
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(Event.NativePreviewEvent event) {
        if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONMOUSEDOWN 
                && event.getNativeEvent().getButton() == Event.BUTTON_RIGHT 
                && event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().equals(element)) {
            showSpecialMenu();
        }
    }
});

Event.sinkEvents(element, Event.ONMOUSEDOWN);
```

Or like this (also you will be able to prevent default context menu):

```
final Element element = menuItem.getElement();
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(Event.NativePreviewEvent event) {
        if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONCONTEXTMENU && event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().equals(element)) {
            // prevent default context menu
            event.getNativeEvent().stopPropagation();
            event.getNativeEvent().preventDefault();

            // show custom context menu
            showSpecialMenu();
        }
    }
});

Event.sinkEvents(element, Event.ONCONTEXTMENU);
```

You can do both like this:

```
......
Event.sinkEvents(element, Event.ONCONTEXTMENU | Event.ONMOUSEDOWN);
```

Comment: Thanks that works great for catching the event but I still see the native context menu instead of mine.

Comment: Strangely the second one doesn't work for me - I never see a ONCONTEXTMENU event thrown.  But for my purposes having a context menu even without supressing the native menu it a big help thanks.

Also I have a hyperlink within the menu item which ends up being the event target so I'm using

    element.toString().contains(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().toString())

Thanks again

Comment: Hmmm. I actually never got this working because I have a hyperlink inside the MenuItem and event comes from the hyperlink but the element was the MenuItem.

In GWT DEvelopment mode it worked great with 

element.toString().contains(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().toString())

but once compiled this fails and I cannot find any way to match the right-click event to which menuItem it came from.  Also the menu item getAbsoluteTop() is zero even when it's visible (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644719/gwt-menuitem-in-a-submenu-has-zero-getabsolutetop-getabsoluteleft)