# GWT MenuItem in a submenu has zero getAbsoluteTop() getAbsoluteLeft()

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to find where a given menu item (which is within a drop down vertical menu) is located on the screen but 
getAbsoluteTop() getAbsoluteLeft() are zero even when the menu item is showing on the screen

The actual Element by the way seems to be

Any idea how I can find where a menu item (within a floating drop down menu) is on the screen please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you ask for the coordinates before the menu item is fully rendered. Try using a Scheduler ([GWT: Timer and Scheduler Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368316/gwt-timer-and-scheduler-classes/12371520#12371520)) to wait until the menu item is fully rendered and then ask for the coordinates inside the `execute` method.

Comment: Thanks, but no the menu has been fully rendered for some seconds already

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? I meant the menu item is fully rendered, not the menu.

Comment: Thanks, but the MenuItem has already been fully rendered and visible for several seconds so I'm already trying this after a delay